# Couldn't find libcgroup.h in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cgroup

`libcgroup.h` is generally located at `/usr/include/libcgroup.h`.

After searching whole file-system ( `find / -type f -name 'libcgroup.h'` ), couldn't find it.

From where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `libcgroup.h` is in the package `libcgroup-dev`. Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install libcgroup-dev
```

Why? That's why:

```
% apt-file search libcgroup.h
libcgroup-dev: /usr/include/libcgroup.h
```

and [that's why](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcgroup.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).